# KendoGrid inline editing with dynamic drop down lists

Tags: kendo-ui

[In this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom), if you click on the category, you'll see a dropdown list to choose the value. What I need is to have the values of the dropdown list depend on a condition, so when you open the dropdown list on different rows you may get different lists.

At the moment I create a row, I have the values to populate the dropdown list, but I'm not sure how to use these values.

This is how I defined the column (I won't be using a template):

```
{ field: "source", title: "Source", width: "180px", editor: srcEditor},
```

And this is the editor:

```
function srcEditor(container, options) {
   $('<input required data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id" 
         data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: sources,
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataValueField: "id"
        });
    }
```

This only works if all the rows have the same dropdown list, but how can I declare a different `srcEditor` for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this statement :

> declare a different srcEditor for each row

You either mean to have

1. entirely **different datasource for each row**,
2. having **same datasource but do some filter if certain condition meet**, or
3. differ in **styling** (for this one simply add class/style)

Solution for number 1 modify your categoryDropDownEditor function, do some conditional to set the url for the datasource and add the different url :

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        var model = options.model;
        var tempDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: ( (model.UnitPrice > 20) ? urlConst.restServiceA : urlConst.restServiceB),
            }
        });
}
```

Solution for number 2 modify your categoryDropDownEditor function and add your condition and do (sor/filter) on parameter map, here's [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/iNUBa) :

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var model = options.model;
    var tempDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories",
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
               console.log("test",operation,operation);
               if (operation == "read" && options) {
               //do your condition here
                  if(model.UnitPrice > 20){
                      tempDataSource.filter({field:"CategoryName", operator:"eq", value: "Condiments"});
                  }
                  return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options, operation);
               }
           }
        },

    });
```

Comment: It's option 1, I have already solve this, the main point here is that the dropdown list function is triggered when the user clicks on a cell, so you populate the dropdown knowing the row index.

Comment: Nice one, just came across something like these on my project, like 1 autocomplete and 1 dropdown connected/trigger filter on each other but differ on each row.